# How to avoid tarfile so that Images should NOT retain the path

Tags: python, tarfile

I am using the tarfile module to compress the image files. But when I compress the images it retain the total path for the images where they are placed.  They should be relative. Means if the Images are placed at location a/b/c/demo_images.png then after extracting the tar.gz it contains the folder also in the extracted part like the same structure a/b/c/demo_images.png but I need only demo_images.png after extraction.

```
tar = tarfile.open(os.path.join(self.image_folder,"Images.tar.gz"),"w:gz")
    for f in image_list:
        tar.add(f,recursive=False)
        try:
            os.unlink(f)
        except OSError as e:
            self.testlog.error(e.errno)
     tar.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tar.add(f, arcname=os.path.basename(f), recursive=False)
```